# Default parameter in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a package xyz like follows :-

```
create or replace package xyz
is 

procedure abc( v_frst_param in VARCHAR2 default 'Y')
IS 

BEGIN

dbms_output.put_line(v_frst_param);
-- CALLING another function

update_table(p_frst_parm =>v_frst_param,
p_second_param =>'2');


END;
```

In the dbms_output.put_line the output is coming null when i am not passing any value while calling abc procedure. 
if i have passed default and i am not passign any parameter shouldnt the value come as Y in the ouput

Comment: Have you set server output to on?

Comment: yes in the output i am getting the other outputs but not this particular value

Comment: do you have the corresponding package body created as well?

Comment: How are you executing this? You have both Toad and plsqldeveloper tags. Are you using one particular tool? Are you executing it by anonymous block that you typed or are you using the tool's execute dialog? If you're using the tool's execute dialog be sure that the param inputs are as you expect. Toad will honor the default value and use that unless you override it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think that package would be invalid, you are trying to add a body for your function in your package specification. However the whole idea is good and it should be working, if done right, for example, create a package:

```
create or replace package xyz is

  procedure abc(v_frst_param in varchar2 default 'Y');

  procedure abc(v_frst_param in varchar2 default 'Y', v_second_param in varchar2);

end xyz;
```

And a package body:

```
create or replace package body xyz is

procedure abc(v_frst_param in varchar2 default 'Y') is
  begin  
    dbms_output.put_line(v_frst_param);  
  end;

procedure abc(v_frst_param in varchar2 default 'Y', v_second_param in varchar2) is
  begin  
    dbms_output.put_line(v_frst_param || ' / ' || v_second_param);  
  end;

end xyz;
```

Then you may want to make the call of your procedure:

```
begin
  xyz.abc;
  xyz.abc(); -- This is the same thing as above
  xyz.abc(v_second_param => 'Maybe');
end;
```

*Please note* that if you send anything as a parameter for v_first_parameter to that procedure, it will use the value you sent and not the default one.

Comment: No, default parameters don't need to be declared last. `abc(a in varchar2 default 'Y', b in varchar2)` is perfectly legal and works fine as long as you use named parameters when calling it.

Comment: Ah, indeed, you are right, thanks, I will fix the answer. I would upvote you comment, but cannot seem able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

Mostly depends on how you are calling your procedure -`ABC();` or `ABC;` or `ABC(NULL);` or `ABC('');` and the way your `parameters` are declared.

```
  Create or replace procedure ABC(v_frst_param IN VARCHAR2 Default 'Y')
    AS
    OUT_v_frst_param  VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN
    OUT_v_frst_param  := v_frst_param ;
    dbms_output.put_line('The PROCEDURE OUTPUT is :  ' || OUT_v_frst_param );
    END;

--Procedure created.

BEGIN
ABC(); --calling procedure
END;

The PROCEDURE OUTPUT is :  Y    
Statement processed.
```

Now if you call your procedure like:

```
BEGIN
ABC; --calling procedure
END;

The PROCEDURE OUTPUT is :  Y
Statement processed.

--passing `NULL`    
BEGIN
ABC(NULL);
END;

The PROCEDURE OUTPUT is :          
Statement processed.

-- Passing  again ''   
BEGIN
ABC('');
END;

The PROCEDURE OUTPUT is :      
Statement processed.

--passing text  
BEGIN
ABC('hello world');
END;

The PROCEDURE OUTPUT is :  hello world    
Statement processed.
```