# Why parameter with default value is null?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I just want to ask a simple question, I have a procedure in my package: procedure(p_x in default sysdate). However, when i try to use this p_x to do query in my procdure, i got nothing from my table. My assumption is p_x does not get value from sysdate and it is null. Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

In Package:

```
Procedure M_m(p_x in default sysdate)
```

In Package Body:

```
Procedure M_m(p_x in default sysdate) as

cursor cur is select manager_id, manager_name,manger_department 
  from employ_table where trunc(EmploymentDate)=trunc(p_x);
r_cur cur%rowtype;

Begin
  for r_cur in cur 
  loop
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(employ_table.manager_id || employ_table.manager_name 
   || employ_table.manager_department);   
end loop;

end;
```

Comment: Perhaps the value is being passed in explicitly as `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi Gordon, why does p_x get null from default value?Normally, p_x should be sysdate, Am i right?

Comment: Please show us the procedure and how you call it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the procedure is updated.

Comment: Thanks, and how do you call it? I think that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 3):

I guess Wernfried is right, it depends on how exactly you call it. Just add a `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_x)` immediately before the `FOR` to verify the value of the variable:

```
CREATE TABLE employ_table AS SELECT * FROM scott.emp;
UPDATE employ_table SET hiredate=SYSDATE WHERE ename='SCOTT';

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE P IS
  PROCEDURE M_m(p_x IN DATE DEFAULT sysdate);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY p IS

  PROCEDURE M_m(p_x IN DATE DEFAULT sysdate) IS
    CURSOR cur IS 
    SELECT * FROM employ_table WHERE TRUNC(hiredate)=TRUNC(p_x);
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('p_x='||p_x); 
    FOR r_cur IN cur LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r_cur.mgr);   
    END LOOP;
  END M_m;

END P;
/

EXEC P.m_m(DATE '1980-12-17');
p_x=1980-12-17 00:00:00
7902

EXEC P.m_m();
p_x=2018-05-26 17:50:11
7566

EXEC P.m_m(NULL);
p_x=
```

Comment: Hi I use oracle sql developer, so when i run it:  

DECLARE  P_XDATE;BEGIN  P_X := NULL;
 PKG_EMPLOYMENT.M_m(    P_x => P_x ) END

Comment: Because my plan is  when i do not type any date, the p_x will get value from sysdate automatically. then it could run the procedure to check any employer's hiredate is equal to sysdate.

Comment: OK, thats the reason then. If you specify anything in the call, even a local variable set to `NULL`, then the default value is not used. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053467/default-parameter-in-oracle-procedure

Answer (score 2):

Currently (as of 18c) the `default` or `:=` clause in a PLSQL parameter specification behaves like a pre-12c `default` clause in a table column definition. That is, the default value is only applied when the corresponding column is not specified at all.

If you define a table column as

```
somedate date default sysdate
```

then it will only be assigned the default value if the `insert` statement does not mention column `somedate` at all. If the `insert` sets `somedate` to `null` then it will be null, regardless of any default. The same behaviour is true of PL/SQL parameters. An explicit `null` value passed in overrides any default that you set for a parameter.

You will need to define a local constant along the lines of

```
k_x constant date := coalesce(p_x,sysdate);
```

and then have the rest of the procedure refer to that instead of the parameter.

In 12c we have `default on null` for table columns, but in my opinion PL/SQL lags behind, as it has no equivalent syntax for parameter defaults. If you pass `null` to a PL/SQL parameter, it respects that `null` and not any default that you specified, as it has no `on null` syntax option.

If you would like Oracle to extend PL/SQL parameter defaults along the same lines as table columns then consider voting for my suggestion here:

https://community.oracle.com/ideas/18189